# Nexus S and gingerbread Sensor events -- Which sensor uses what hardware?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sdk-2.3, nexus-s, tilt-sensor

Could someone help to know which sensor uses which part of phone's hardware or in what combination of this on Nexus S in android 2.3 ?

Following are the sensor events:

TYPE_ACCELEROMETER

TYPE_GYROSCOPE

TYPE_GRAVITY

TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION

TYPE_ORIENTATION

TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

I assume first 2 corresponds to separate hardware (accelerometer and gyroscope),

but how with the other remaining ones ?

**Does TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION uses both Acceleromter and Gyroscope hardware at its best?**

I am actually interested in "linear aceleration" so should I need not worry about gyro events, if "linear acceleration" internally uses gyro to give out values ?

Also when tested on device linear accelerations found to give high values for minor shakes , so assuming this removes gravity vector, this was not expected.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered here by Mathias Agopian.

[Google Groups Android discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/18e9bdca14c565a3/2614b252b9d82c78?lnk=raot)